# Disable delete or undo gesture in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, touchpad, logitech-keyboard

I got a new logitech wireless keyboard that has a touch-pad on it, it's apparently multi touch as I can do pinch zoom, etc... .

Every once in a while (read only when writing something important) I'll acidently swipe in a certian direction and it will erase what I just wrote and I can't get it back. I don't know if it's doing undo or erase, but it's not fun. How can I disable that gesture?

Comment: If you install the software there is likely an option to disable it.

Comment: To reiterate @Ramhound's comment, **did** your new keyboard come with a management tool software? Many times keyboards like these don't offer full or intended functionality if you rely on Windows drivers.

Comment: No i don't have any of the keyboard software installed. I don't really think installing bloatware so I can DiSABle a "feature" is a good plan either. But if that's my only option, oh well.

Comment: Can you provide the model number of the keyboard. I'm guessing it's a [K400](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16823126264)